# Grub repair unsuccessful, boot to grub rescue>. Trying to boot from sda4 (ubuntu 14.04), sda2 has broken kernel ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I have a broken boot on a linux server that has 4 partitions (sda1-4).

We had a boot issue and resolved it by running grub repair. Once rebooted we updated to Ubuntu 16.04 (on sda2 where all our working directories are). The update resulted in a broken desktop where we couldn't sign in users (put password in and then screen flash and went back to user login). The partition was almost full, so it's possible the update wasn't complete, however, there was no error message.

Made new boot partition (sda4) with Ubuntu 14.04 and tried to delete Ubuntu 16.04, in case it was causing interference, from sda2 by booting from live CD with commands below, however it's still there. Also deleted files from sda2 to make space.

```
       sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
       sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
       sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
       sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
       sudo chroot /mnt
       apt-get remove --purge linux-headers_4.4.8*
       apt-get remove --purge image-headers_4.4.8*
```

Tried boot repair after removal.
It boots to grub rescue>
I tried boot repair again and the log is here http://paste.ubuntu.com/23549041/

I noticed that for sda4 there is no "boot sector" information, is this the issue?

Any help is very-much appreciated!!!

Edited to include df:

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/cow             32979776      43984   32935792   1% /
udev             32935276          4   32935272   1% /dev
tmpfs             6595956       1252    6594704   1% /run
/dev/sr0           987136     987136          0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0         944256     944256          0 100% /rofs
none                    4          0          4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs            32979776       1028   32978748   1% /tmp
none                 5120          4       5116   1% /run/lock
none             32979776         76   32979700   1% /run/shm
none               102400         48     102352   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2      7338794732 5768586068 1200331900  83% /media/ubuntu/b697f249-e945-46f0-898b-438a8da6b100
/dev/sda4        47115636    4139200   40560052  10% /media/ubuntu/3ad839ec-2ceb-4123-aaa2-396634fde7bc
```

[gparted screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKrS4.png)

Edit: New Boot Repair Report post Ubuntu 16.04 updates paste.ubuntu.com/23549880/

Comment: Your two Boot Repair Report links are identical.

Comment: It looks like your swap is a problem. Not seen this much with gpt. "/dev/sda2 overlaps with /dev/sda3" I might delete swap & recreate at end of drive so it does not interfere with partitions. You may need to use gdisk to repair partition table. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/ and: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html Never install grub to a partition, it really does not fit and converts to blocklists. But is not directly bootable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem when updated to Ubuntu 16.04 on sda2 (where all our working directories are). The update resulted in a broken desktop where we couldn't sign in users (put password in and then screen flash and went back to user login). The partition was almost full, so it's possible the update wasn't complete, however, there was no error message.

This problem was not a boot problem. Your comment about the almost-full partition suggests that this may in fact have been the cause. If so, deleting unnecessary files, perhaps in conjunction with resolving APT update issues, might have resolved the problem. You might still be able to do this with the help of an emergency disk and `chroot` procedures, but I make no promises of this and I don't have a step-by-step procedure handy.

If you want more help on this, you should begin by providing information on the disk space used and available on all your partitions. Typing `df` in a Terminal *while all partitions are mounted* will display this information, so you should post that output. If you do so, be sure to edit your original question, adding four spaces to the start of each line of the `df` output to keep it legible.

> Made new boot partition (sda4) with Ubuntu 14.04 and tried to delete Ubuntu 16.04

...

> Tried boot repair after removal. It boots to grub rescue>

GRUB relies on files scattered about here and there. It sounds like, in your effort to resolve the problem, you accidentally deleted the `grub.cfg` file. Running Boot Repair again *should* fix this problem, but your configuration is now complex enough (with two Ubuntu installations) that I can make no promises of that. Even if you get the system booting again, you'll be back to your original problem.

> I noticed that for sda4 there is no "boot sector" information, is this the issue?

No. In most BIOS-mode Ubuntu boot configurations, GRUB goes in the MBR of the hard disk, in either post-MBR unallocated sectors (on MBR disks) or in the BIOS Boot Partition (on GPT disks, like yours), and in files in the `/boot/grub` directory. GRUB goes in a partition's partition boot record (PBR) only if you install GRUB there and use something else (like the Windows boot loader) in the MBR, which you are *not* doing.

Incidentally, you're doing a BIOS-mode boot on a GPT disk. This was working fine for you, but if your computer has an EFI (as do most sold since late 2011), you might want to consider switching to EFI-mode booting. This will require some reconfiguration, but it's often a little bit faster and, once you understand how it works, it can be a little more flexible and less flaky. The drawback is that "once you understand how it works" caveat; there's still a lot of misinformation about EFI-mode booting floating around, and if you're well-versed in BIOS-mode booting, you'll need to re-learn a lot of fiddly little details. See [Adam Williamson's blog entry on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/) and [my page on installing Linux on EFI systems](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) for more on EFI-mode booting generally. There are also flaky EFIs still available, and the worst of these can be worse than BIOS-mode booting, even for experts. Note that switching to EFI-mode booting will *not* fix your initial login problem; but you could implement such a switch as a way to fix the more fundamental boot problem you've created for yourself. Switching from BIOS-mode to EFI-mode booting while fixing a problem like yours may be too much effort, so you may just want to keep this in mind as a future project. (OTOH, maybe you'll find a way to fix your immediate boot problems in EFI mode.)

---

***EDIT:***

So are you still getting the `grub>` prompt after clearing off some space and running Boot Repair again? If so, I'm not sure what the problem is. I have two shot-in-the-dark suggestions, though:

- If your computer uses EFI (as do most sold since late 2011), you could download the CD-R or USB flash drive version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html), prepare a boot medium, and boot with it. rEFInd should enable you to boot either of your installations, assuming their kernels and boot files are intact. You could then fix things up, add an [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) and install rEFInd on your hard disk. This is the safest approach at this point, but it will work *only* if your computer uses an EFI.
- Delete one of your two Ubuntu partitions (`/dev/sda2` or `/dev/sda4`) and run Boot Repair again. The idea here is that Boot Repair may be getting confused by the presence of two Ubuntu installations, and therefore creating an invalid GRUB setup. Eliminating one of the Ubuntu installations should then make it easier for Boot Repair to do its job. This approach is risky, though, especially if you accidentally delete the wrong installation. Even if you delete the right Ubuntu, the remaining one might be damaged in some fundamental way or something else might be causing Boot Repair to mess up.

If neither of these approaches work, you may need to either become quite the expert on GRUB, so as to fix it manually; or back up your personal files, re-install Ubuntu from scratch, and restore your personal files.

Comment: thanks so much for your time on this Rod Smith. I've edited my question to provide information on the disk space used and available on all partitions. I have the output from df and also a screenshot of gparted since I couldn't mount some partitions to get info from df.

Comment: I tried to update and fix Ubuntu 16.04 after deleting unnecessary files and makes room on sda2. I than ran grub repair. I have a new boot repair report http://paste.ubuntu.com/23549880/

Comment: Please see my edit, above.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions everyone. Rod we're going to try to delete one of the partitions next. First we tried moving the SWAP partition like oldfred suggested and unfortunately that didn't work.